# Unable to understand web.xml mapping and package definitions

Tags: web-services, jakarta-ee, web.xml

My web.xml is

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>SwipeXBackendServices</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages</param-name>
        <param-value>com.mycompany.backend.webservices</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>SwipeXBackendServices</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/webservices/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Why does the mapping have to be `/webservices/*` and not `com.mycompany.backend.webservices/*`.

This is my webservice code

```
package com.swipex.backend.webservices;

@Path("/Activation")
public class Activation {
    private static final Logger log = Logger.getLogger(Activation.class);
    private DeviceDetails deviceDetailsTable = DeviceDetails.getInstance();

    @POST
    @Path("Request")
    @Consumes({ MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON })
    public Response post(JAXBElement<CDeviceDetails> device) {
```

**Edit : Junit Client Code**

```
@Test
    public void testPost() throws Exception {
        /*
         * Activate
         */
        // Initialize Web Services
        ClientConfig config = new DefaultClientConfig();
        Client client = Client.create(config);

        //
        // Activation Service
        //
        URI url = UriBuilder.fromUri(
                "http://" + SERVER + "/SwipeXBackEnd/Activation/Request")
                .build();
        WebResource service = client.resource(url);
        System.out.println(url);
        // Get the data ready
        CDeviceDetails newDevice = new CDeviceDetails(null, "mac id", "model",
                "manufacturer", "androidVersion", Calendar.getInstance()
                        .getTime(), "buildID", "fingerPrint", "board",
                "bootLoader", "hardware", "id", "product", "serial", Calendar
                        .getInstance().getTime(), Calendar.getInstance()
                        .getTime(), Globals.ACTIVE);
        String deviceUniqueIdentity = service.type(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                .post(String.class, newDevice);
        assertNotNull(deviceUniqueIdentity);
        System.out.println("Activation Passed " + deviceUniqueIdentity);
```

Comment: Like the rest of JEE its massively over engineered to take account of numerous hypothetical situations, when, 99.9% of users just want to associate a java class and method with a URL pattern.

Comment: Thank god someone agrees with me.. Make me feel less of a fool.

Answer (score 1):

Url pattern doesn't have any relationship with your java package structure. In your case, you've mapped the **SwipeXBackendServices** servlet to listen on the '**/webservices**' url (ex : `http://localhost:8080/webservices/`). i.e., when a request comes for '/webservices', it'll be routed to your 'SwipeXBackendServices' servlet class.

And also your jax-rs (rest) class '**Activation**' is mapped to the url '**/activation**' (ex : `http://localhost:8080/activation`).

**Mapping of url & class :**

```
/webservices ===> SwipeXBackendServices
/activation  ===> Activation
```

So, don't confuse the package name with the url name.

Comment: In the catalina log file I notice that these classes were loaded 
`class com.swipex.backend.webservices.Activation class com.swipex.backend.webservices.Registration`

Comment: Where is the URL that it works with mentioned ? New to webservices, hence the questions.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26097993/where-do-i-verify-the-load-path-for-my-rest-webservice. Please help.

Answer (score 1):

As Sriram says the servlet mappings have no relation with the packages.

The `com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages` parameter for the `SwipeXBackendServices` servlet just tells Jersey which package to scan for discovering REST resources.

The `servlet-mapping` for the `SwipeXBackendServices` servlet tells the servlet container on which URLs the servlet will answer. In this case, it will answer to all URLs prefixed with `/webservices`. Meaning that all REST resources will be prefixed with `/webservices`.

Then, the URLs for any REST resource will be the concatenation of

- The WAR context root
- The Jersey servlet mapping
- The REST resource path (being itself the concatenation of the class's path and the method's path)

Hence, assuming the context root for your WAR is `/myWebApp`, the URL for a `POST` request to your `Activation` resource will be: `http://localhost:8080/myWebApp/webservices/Activation/Request`

Comment: So I have `<servlet-name>SwipeXBackEnd</servlet-name> <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>` and I called `http://localhost:8080/SwipeXBackEnd/Activation/Request`. I still get a 404

Comment: Is `SwipeXBackEnd` the context root for your web application? Try maybe `/*` instead of `/` for the pattern.  Also note that is responds on `POST` requests only, if you try with a browser it sends `GET` requests by default. You may try adding `@GET` on your method for testing.